# Validator on a Django form field gives Attribute Error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I made a validator for a field on a Django form I made. Here is the validator:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

def validate_value(value):
    if value.isalpha():
        if len(value) != 1:
            raise ValidationError(
                ugettext_lazy('Invalid zone value: %(value)s'),
                params={'value': value}
            )
    elif value.isdecimal():
        if int(value) == 0:
            raise ValidationError(
                ugettext_lazy('Invalid zone value: %(value)s'),
                params={'value': value}
            )
    else:
        raise ValidationError(
            ugettext_lazy('Invalid zone value: %(value)s'),
            params={'value': value}
        )
```

What this validator does is take in a string and see if it's either a single letter or a number. If it's none of those or that number equals zero, then it raises the validation error. For example, "a" and "3" will be accepted, but "a1" will raise the error. Below is the form that the validator is attached to:

```
from django import forms
from values.validators import validate_value

class LetterOrNumberForm(forms.Form):
    value = forms.CharField(validators=[validate_value])
```

The problem comes when I test the form. What the form should do when a bad input is entered is show the validation error above the field. When I put in a value that is supposed to pass, like "a" or "3", the form works fine. But when I put in a bad input such as "a1", Django crashes and I get this error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'
```

The template and view is pretty standard for Django forms so I doubt the problem is there, and if I take that validator and configure it to be in the clean function of the form, it actually works. However, I want to use the validator. Does anyone know what could be causing the problem? Thanks.

Comment: When you submit say "a1", what is actually getting passed for `value` to the validator? It looks like `None`, which would error accordingly. A debugging print statement (or looking at the stack trace of a failed submit) would be very helpful.

Comment: I put print(value) in the validator function before the if statement, put another code under the function validate_value('a1'), and then ran the validator file directly. The value does print out, followed by the validation error. Perhaps the validation error itself is causing the problem concerning the form?

Comment: It implies to me that the form and validator might be fine, but there might be an issue with the view and how it's handling values from POST or GET.

Comment: Please post the entire traceback of the exception (why don't people do that by default is a mystery to me).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Turns out that it was something else in the form code that was causing the problem, not the validator itself.